# Imagem é gravada na pasta que eu criei e outra na galeria da câmera

Tags: java, android

Estou com o seguinte problema tenho um app, que tira foto porém e dispositivo motorola está gravando na galeria além de gravar na pasta que eu falei que seria.

```
  Intent photo = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    photo.putExtra("outputFormat",Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG.toString());

    File file = new File(...função retorna pasta);
    Uri photoURI;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
      //proveder
    } else {
        photoURI = Uri.fromFile(file);
    }
    photo.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    photo.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
    photo.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);

   Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
 startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

tem alguma flag ou forma que passo para a intent e o soft câmera não grava na pasta padrão dele e somente na minha que foi definida

Comment: Tem a certeza que a foto é gravada em duas pastas?

Comment: Sim deleto de uma e na outra se mante, uma grava com o nome da câmera padrão img_[data_hora], já a da pasta temp criada grava com o nome predefinido.

Comment: no ASUS foi normal ele não grava, por enquanto  só foi notado no Motorola